# Fill is not working in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, fill-paragraph, auto-fill-mode

While in `org-mode` I've tried calling `fill-paragraph` directly.  I've tried using `auto-fill-mode` and `refill-mode`.  I've tried `org-fill-paragraph`.  The `fill-column` is set appropriately.  None of them make the fill happen; absolutely no changes occur.

Does anyone know if this is a known bug or is otherwise a problem? Even better, do you know of a solution?

Comment: In what context is it not filling, and could you provide some example text that is not filling?  Also: do you still have the problem if you start emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`)?

Comment: @Dan Thank you for the `emacs -Q` suggestion.  That made it clear (removed distractions).  I was expecting headers to wrap and apparently they just don't.  Non-header paragraphs are wrapping just fine.

Comment: Great.  If you've figured out the problem, please write up a short answer, post it, and then accept it (once the system allows you to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator Error: After getting a suggestion from @Dan ( `emacs -Q` ), I tried org-mode again.  With distractions out of the way it became clear that headers and paragraphs are treated differently.  I was expecting a header to wrap, but they don't.  Paragraphs are wrapping just fine with no fixes required.

Comment:  but I want headlines to also wrap